# Angular JS - get selected text as ng model (without ng-options)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

In my code behind, I fill up a DropDownList as follows (using VB)

```
ddlCountries.DataSource = dt ' dt is DataTable with columns "CountryCode" and "CountryName"
ddlCountries.DataTextField = "CountryName"
ddlCountries.DataValueField = "CountryCode"
ddlCountries.DataBind()
ddlCountries.Attributes.Add("ng-model", "CountryName")
```

Then client side, I have a select tag, which is filled with options from server side as below:

```
<select ng-model="CountryName">
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="ML">Malaysia</option>
    <!-- and other 200+ records -->
</select>
```

I can't use `ng-options` here! Now, whenever I change the value from `select`, I get `CountryName` as `IN`, `US`, `ML` etc.. Moreover, I can't edit values of options because they're used in server side code.

Here I want `CountryName` as `India`, `United States` or `Malaysia` instead! What can I do?

Comment: `<option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>`

Comment: Can't do that... @KalhanoToressPamuditha

Comment: There's not a clean way of doing what you want. It's better to have the server send the value as what you want.

Comment: Why cant you use ng-options (get the country list from the server and bind it)?

Comment: @PSL If I write something like `item.name for item in items`, the `select` becomes empty

Comment: @RuchirGupta Can you show.. what you mean by select becomes empty? and how does the items look like?

Comment: post ur `items` structure ?

Comment: all the `option` tags which are inside `select` tag disappear! @PSL

Comment: @RuchirGupta That could be because you are not using it the way it needs to be, or your data structure is not what you think it is. Unless you show us how you are using it, it would be difficult for us to guess what the issues is.

Comment: I can't populate the `items` to fill up inside the `select` in my javascript because it is populated from server side! So I can't get the item structure in javascript! Is there any advice accept using `ng-options`?

Comment: then how u get this output ?

Comment: @RuchirGupta Is this html being constructed from the server?

Comment: Ok i saw your update. What is the problem if ng-model is the value? It is appropriate and also it is not difficult to get the text from value right? SInce you already have this list on the server. Create a custom directive to set the ng-model accordingly then.

Comment: @PSL Rather than answering me, you are misleading and more confusing... What if I want to populate the `CountryName` in some label? If you can, just answer to my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What data is the server sending you?

Is it some array of objects like this?

```
var countries = [ 
    { name: 'India', code: 'IN'},
    { name: 'United States', code: 'US'},
    { name: 'Malaysia', code: 'ML'}
];
```

If yes, then you can easily use ng-options (even though you dont have to, its just better).

```
<select ng-model="CountryName"
    ng-options="c.code as c.name for c in countries">
</select>
```

Or in the case that you actually are working with server side generated html page and no javascript objects, then its a little bit tricker:
(Supposing you can use JQuery):

view:

```
<select id="countryNameSelect" ng-change="setCountryName()">
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="ML">Malaysia</option>
    <!-- and other 200+ records -->
</select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.countryName = '';
$scope.setCountryName = function() {
  $scope.countryName = $("#countryNameSelect option:selected").html();
};
```

Comment: @PSL: Well its just reading values, not manipulating :) But yea, you are right that this isnt conceptually a very good solution.

Comment: Not just manipulation, controller should not know or access DOM.. Controllers are not for that. That is why you have directive's linking /compile functions. That is how it should be designed, It is a poor practice IMHO (and i am sure most people would agree with me)

Comment: @JoeSamanek Works for me!! Will wait for if I get a better solution!

Comment: @PSL: Yea but problem is that if we dont have the data other than in html, we need to access it to get the desired values. It doesnt have to be in the controller, but it needs to be somewhere.

Comment: Plenty of ways to access via AngularJS, DOM manipulation not worth it

Answer (score 2):

**In PHP BackEnd array to Json Out: < ? php echo json_encode($arrayDemo); ? >**

```
// Init Load
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('ngjsapp', [])
        .controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            var myArraySelect = <?php echo json_encode($arrayDemo); ?>

            $scope.changeSenasaProvinciasId = function (id) {
                console.log(myArraySelect[id]);
            }

        }]);
});
```

**Only HTML Stact + jQuery**

```
// Option 1
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('ngjsapp', [])
        .controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.changeSenasaProvinciasId = function () {
                console.log($("#mySelectID option:selected").text());
            }

        }]);
});
```

**Only HTML Stact + jQuery BEST**

```
// Option 2
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('ngjsapp', [])
        .controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            var myArraySelect = $('#mySelectID option').each( function() { 
                    myArraySelect.push({$(this).val() : $(this).text() });
                });

            $scope.changeSenasaProvinciasId = function (id) {
                console.log(myArraySelect[id]);
            }

        }]);
});
```

Comment: They can also see this other solution that implements here.
AngularJS 100% pure, without any Jquery as people recommend AngularJS for good practices, avoid jquery.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604956/how-to-get-text-and-value-in-element-select-by-id-100-angularjs/