# Angular JS ng-show/ hide based on drop-down list selected value

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

in the following code I have one drop-down list (serviceSmallId) for type of service.
It is populated using model info.

There is a second field check-box which should only be visible when drop-down has a selected value of 'Weekly'. I am trying to use ng-show/ hide of angular.

I tried to search for possible solutions but no luck. 
Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong.

```html
<section id="scrubber-view" class="mainbar" data-ng-controller="scrubber as vm">
    <section class="matter">
        <div class="container">

            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="vm.goBack()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Back</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="vm.cancel()" ng-disabled="!vm.canSave"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i>Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="vm.save()" ng-disabled="!vm.canSave"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save</button>
                <span ng-show="vm.hasChanges" style="color:orange" class="dissolve-animation ng-hide"><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></span>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="widget wblue">
                    <div data-cc-widget-header title="{{vm.title}}" subtitle="{{vm.scrubber.scrubberId}}"></div>

                    <form class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="serviceSmallId" class="col-sm-2">Service</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <select class="form-control" id="serviceSmallId" ng-model="vm.scrubber.serviceSmallId"
                                        ng-options="item.dataLookupId as item.description for item in vm.serviceSmalls | orderBy:['sortOrder','description']">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>



 <div class="form-group" ng-show="vm.scrubber.serviceSmallId.value=='Weekly'">
                            <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="fullyFlanged" value="Bar" />
                        </div>

 </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is a more elegant "angular way" solution,

but I updated you code to work **here** - http://jsbin.com/tupisoriho/1/edit?html,js,output

#### Explanation of changes

- Provided `ng-show` a value `vm.checker`
- added `ng-change` to the select element and gave it a function `checkerGo` which tested to see if dropdown == 'weekly', if yes change `vm.checker`

#### Update

there **is** a more "angular way" - using expressions!
As per @Omri Aharon fiddle/comment below.

Comment: Great, I would be keen to see how that would work, I just haven't been able to get expressions to work.

Comment: Hi, thanks I got this working. However vm.scrubber.serviceSmallId returns value of the selected option which is a GUI. Hence I modified the js to:       if (chk == 'DCC69AB8-A41C-49AF-95DB-864AB9380C0F'). instead of if (chk === 'weekly') . I was wondering if there is a way by which I could check the description of selected item instead of value (GUI in this case) ?

Comment: Got it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426539/angular-js-get-selected-text-as-ng-model-without-ng-options

Comment: @Max You shouldn't do JQuery when you're using Angular, and certainly not manipulate the DOM at the controller. Use the above solution if you can't do it otherwise, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the value property because a ng-model don't hold the element but the value itself;

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-show="vm.scrubber.serviceSmallId.value=='Weekly'">
```

must be

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-show="vm.scrubber.serviceSmallId == 'Weekly'">
```

EDIT: In your case `vm.scrubber.serviceSmallId` will contain the ID and not the description `Weekly`. I suggest you to use `ng-change` directive to call a function in your controller that will find the item based on ID and set in the controller to be visible for ng-show.

```
  <select class="form-control" id="serviceSmallId" ng-model="vm.scrubber.serviceSmallId"
            ng-options="item.dataLookupId as item.description for item in vm.serviceSmalls | orderBy:['sortOrder','description']"
            ng-change="vm.selectObj()">
```

`vm.selectObj()` will find and set the current selected object in the scope to an controller variable (ex.: `vm.selectedItem`) and:

```
  <div class="form-group" ng-show="vm.selectedItem.description=='Weekly'">
```

Comment: Hi nanndoj, thanks for your response but I already tried removing ".value" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: is 'Weekly' the option's value or the description? `<option value="Weekly">...</option>` or `<option value="...">Weekly</option>`

Comment: 'Weekly' is the description, value is a unique identifier.