# How to get Text and Value in element SELECT by #ID 100% AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, select

There is a better way to do AngularJS, with fewer lines of code that my example ..?
The idea is to make it 100% with AngularJS and jqLite.

**Link Example My CODE solution:**  http://jsfiddle.net/EOM/xecymL9t/

**HTML:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="Main" data-ng-app>

  <select id="yo" data-ng-model="selection" data-ng-change="sample(selection)" required="required">
    <option value="11" selected="selected">Name 2</option>
    <option value="10">Name 1</option>
    <option value="">SELECT DEFAULT ANGULAR INIT</option>
    <option value="12">Name 3</option>
  </select>
```

View Show in Console to Browser (F12)

**AngularJS:**

```
function Main($scope, $document) {

$scope.sample = function(myvalue) {
        // Get By ID
        var e = $document[0].getElementById('yo');
    // Get all options select
    e = angular.element(e).find('option');
    // Loop
    angular.forEach(e, function(v, k){
        // Is option selected..?
        if(angular.element(v).prop('selected')){
        // Get Text option selected
        console.log('Text: '+angular.element(v).text()); // Text
      }
    });
    console.log('Value: '+myvalue) // Value
}}
```

Comment: Only AngularJS and jqLite, no vanilla JS?

Comment: this link may help you: https://exhesham.com/2017/11/20/text-highlight-manipulation-with-angular2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on solution "**jbMartinez**", I saw a simpler solution shortens the handles.
And retrieve the text of the option selected.

With respect to compatibility "**Niclas Larsson**" is to have **>= IE9** or higher, since I am using **AngularJS 1.5.0** and it does not support for **<= IE8**

Are saying, see it as a final solution or it may be a better way ..?

**Code Example only change in JS:**

```
function Main($scope, $document) {

$scope.sample = function(myvalue) {

    var myval = (myvalue)?myvalue:'';
    // Get text select
    var mytext = $document[0].querySelector('#yo [value="' + myval + '"]').text;
    // Show Text option selected in console
    console.log('Text: '+mytext); // Text
    console.log('Value: '+myval) // Value

} }
```

**Link Example Run** [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/EOM/xecymL9t/4/)

Comment: This isn't "100% pure angularjs" as qwas requested - this incorporates jquery into the mix. Is there a way to do this purely in angularJs?

Comment: Hi, PKD, error not is jquery, is "AngularJS + jqLite". Please view code example not exist lib jquery. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shorter, but I don't know if you consider it 100% AngularJS + jqLite. [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) say you should use standard DOM APIs for advanced queries (jqLite's `find` is limited to lookups by tag name)

```
function Main($scope, $document) {

  $scope.sample = function(myvalue) {
    var e = $document[0].getElementById('yo')
      .querySelector('[value="' + myvalue + '"]');

    // Get Text option selected
    console.log('Text: '+angular.element(e).text()); // Text
    console.log('Value: '+myvalue) // Value
  }
}
```

You can check the the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xecymL9t/1/)

Comment: I would use `.querySelector('option:checked')`, since there could be more than one option with the same value. But `:checked` would not work in IE < 9.

Comment: jbmartinez, code mini fix, show in print: http://s19.postimg.org/cxqh669er/Print_De_Pantalla_241.jpg